# Which theorem(s) apply: If $P(X \leq 0)$ and $E(x)$ exists, then $P(X \geq 2\mu) \leq \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: probability-theory

I have been asked to show the statement in the title to be true. I wish I had some work to show for this, but I am staring at a list of theorems and for the life of me can't figure out which one will help me start this problem. I am not looking for a full proof, just some intuition and perhaps a nudge down one of the following paths:

- If $E(Y^{2m})$ exists for $m\gt 0$ then $\forall m \gt 0$, then
  $P(\left|Y\right| \geq \epsilon) \leq
     \frac{E(Y^{2m})}{\epsilon^{2m}}$
- $P(|x-\mu| \geq \epsilon) \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{\epsilon^2}$
- If $m=1$ and $Y=X-\mu$ and $\sigma^{2} \lt \infty$, then 
  $P(\left|x-\mu \right| \geq \epsilon) \leq
     \frac{\sigma^2}{\epsilon^2}$

And finally,

- If $\epsilon = k\sigma$ then $P(\left|x-\sigma\right| \gt k\sigma)\le
     \frac{1}{k^2}$

Answer (score 0):

What about $P(X\geq \epsilon)\leq \frac{E[X]}{\epsilon}$, the simplest form of the Markov/Chebyshev inequality. Afterall, $X$ is non-negative almost-surely.